# New column issue after association

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I created 2 tables in Visual studio say TA and TB. In edmx file I made 1-to-many association between TA and TB. After making association, a new column is generated in TB named `TAId`.

I just want to know whether I have to add that column in the TB table in database?

**EDIT :**  Exception I got:

> nCeremony.msl(23,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at 
>       line 23: No mapping specified for properties CourseOption.MenuId in Set
>        CourseOptions.
>
> An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>
> Entity is type [CeremonyDBModel.CourseOption]
>
> Ceremony.msl(31,10) : 
>        error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 31:No mapping 
>        specified for properties Menu.CeremonyId in Set Menus.
>
> An Entity with Key (PK) 
>       will not round-trip when:
>
> Entity is type [CeremonyDBModel.Menu]

Comment: Do you have any other column in TB that represents the primary key of the parent record from TA?

Comment: Then you have to go with the Visula Studio suggestion and add the TA_ID column to table TB.

Comment: yes i did that but when i update the model from data base then it again generate a new column with the TA_ID_1 name

Answer (score 0):

A one-to-many association is done by having records in a child table reference their parent.

Consider an example of customers and purchases. A customer may make many purchases, but each purchase can only belong to one customer. Consider the following two tables:

```
customers     purchases
============  ===========
id  name      id  customer_id  product
```

Each customer has a unique ID and a name. Each purchase also has a unique ID and a product name. However, in order to have a one-to-many association, the purchases table must *also* reference which customer made the purchase. You couldn't do this in reverse, or you would have duplicate names of customers each referencing some purchase.

For example:

```
customers     purchases
============  ===========
id  name      id  customer_id  product
--- --------  --- ------------ --------
1   John      1   1            apple
2   Mary      2   1            orange
              3   2            banana
```

In this example you can see that John purchased an apple and a orange, and Mary purchased a Banana.

The `customer_id` column is necessary for the purchases table to establish the relationship with the customers table.

By creating the association between your TA and TB tables, Visual Studio has created the column `TAid` for you, because that is how relational databases like MS SQL Server handle them.

Comment: But this column is not present in the database table, so thats why i am getting the exception when i run my application, why?

Comment: If you're getting an exception when you try to run the app, you should post the exception text in the question.

Comment: sorry but i just posted the exception text, take a look please

Comment: Hopefully someone will be able to help; unfortunately I am not at all familiar with the type of exception you got.